# The USING clause in Laravel's query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

There are already several open questions about this. As of Laravel 5, it seems that there is no solution to this problem but now newer versions of Laravel are out there.

By `USING`, I am refering to the SQL command that is used when joining two tables. I can't use `ON` instead as it seems to run into other problems like ambiguities and having to turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Is it possible to somehow add USING to a Laravel query builder statement? Other than writing the whole query as a raw query, of course.